# Facebook OAuthException, code: 1, An error occured while creating the share [HTTP 400])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am building a facebook app on rails and using koala gem to interact with facebook api. Clicking a button makes an ajax call to vote.js.erb 
The following code in vote.js.erb

`<%- current_voter.facebook.put_wall_post("Just a little post, thats all", "link" => "http://umedwar.herokuapp.com/candidates/1") -%>`

throws following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: (#1) An error occured while creating the share [HTTP 400]):

There is a mention of the error here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ but I still can not figure out how to make this work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more code for someone to truly diagnose this problem.

Are you instantiating the koala facebook client with the current_voter's oauth_token like so:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_voter.oauth_access_token)
```

See the koala readme here, which shows you how to do that. https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Comment: I know i sound stupid but the same code is working somehow. thanks for the prompt reply. still it would help to know what conditions exactly throw this error.